# dynamo db local shell doesn't list tables using docker image

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am using docker enabled dynamoDB local as mentioned [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local)

and following is my JS code:

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'sas',
  endpoint:  'http://docker.for.mac.host.internal:8000' //'http://localhost:8000'
});
```

and create table function  below:

```
function createTable() {
    let params = {
        TableName: 'sas',
        KeySchema: [{
            AttributeName: 'title',
            KeyType: 'HASH',
        }],
        AttributeDefinitions: [{
            AttributeName: 'title',
            AttributeType: 'S'
        }],
        ProvisionedThroughput: {
            ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
            WriteCapacityUnits: 1,
        }
    };
    dynamoDB.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err); // an error occurred
        else
            console.log(data);
    });
}
```

i could see created table **sas** using cli :

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --region=sas
```

but NOT listing the table in the and it's always empty.

```
http://localhost:8000/shell/
```

any idea's?

NOTE:
i can see my table with above code, by running dynamodb jar locally

```
 java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

Comment: for me, what did the trick was to check the region in my .aws\config file and set it the same as the one you mention in your JS code - sas (for me it is set to eu-west-2), maybe it helps someone ...

Answer (score 17):

make sure you are also passing -sharedDb to the docker image.

If -sharedDb is not present then dynamodb-local will use
access keys+region as namespaces to separate tables
(as if they were under different aws accounts)

Comment: It wouldn't work for me by just adding `-sharedDb` to the Docker run command. I had to use `docker run -p 8000:8000 amazon/dynamodb-local -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

Comment: @andyberry88 great, this finally worked! Also don't forget you have to re-create the tables after you first started with `-sharedDb`.

Comment: I was trying to do it with `docker-compose` instead but couldn't find a way to have the tables listed in the /shell. Running it with `docker` directly worked.

Comment: I was able to do it with docker compose.  I overrode the command like this:  `command: -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb`

Answer (score 14):

As [@Mendhak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974369/mendhak) points out in the comments on [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54718308/dynamo-db-local-shell-doesnt-list-tables-using-docker-image/54726805#54726805), if you are using docker-compose, you will need to share the db, which you can do by overriding the `command` in *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  dynamodb-local:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local:latest
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

I didn't see this anywhere in the sprawling AWS docs, so I wanted to leave this answer to improve visibility for other wandering devs.

**Credit to Mendhak** - you could upvote his comment as well as this answer, if it helped you!

Answer (score 4):

You can specify -sharedDb param when start docker dynamodb.

```
docker run -itd -p 8000:8000  --name dev-db amazon/dynamodb-local:latest -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```